# Changing paragraph width in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox on the form:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="TextArea"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

At runtime I add paragraph with border using this code:

```
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
Inline hello = new Run("Hello") { FontSize = 14 };
Inline world = new Run("World") { FontSize = 20, Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) };
Inline helloWorld = new Run(Environment.NewLine + "Hello World");
p1.Inlines.Add(hello);
p1.Inlines.Add(world);
p1.Inlines.Add(helloWorld);
p1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
p1.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue);
p1.Padding = new Thickness(2);
this.TextArea.Document.Blocks.Add(p1);
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Current picture]

But I want it to be like this:

[image: Desired picture]

[image]

Is there any simple way to set paragraph width (or outer frame size) equal to its content?

Comment: I think is the Grid's fault, change the grid to a canvas, or set the RichTextBox Width property to auto or a determined size.

Comment: try enclose `RichTextBox` in a `StackPanel`?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but changing the Width property of the RichTextBox partly solves my problem. I would like to have many paragraphs with different content bounded with border with appropriate size

Comment: Create Grid.Columns and Grid.Rows and set height / width to auto.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way, so that the border will be invisible

1.XML

```
   <Grid>
       <RichTextBox x:Name="TextArea" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0"/>
   </Grid>
```

2.Code behind

```
  TextArea.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);//No border
  TextArea.Padding = new Thickness(0); //text padding
  TextArea.Margin = new Thickness(10); // margin of txtbox
```

Answer (score 0):

TextBox can get own content width.
RichTextBox can't get own content width.
So binding transparent TextBox width.
But this width is not so much correct.
You need a bit of contrivance more.(For example, prepare plural TextBox?)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="ShadowArea" Visibility="Hidden" Padding="5,0" FontSize="20" Height="20" Text="Add same string"/>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="TextArea" Width="{Binding ElementName=ShadowArea, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```